# ClassNotFoundException with Mockito 2 in OSGI

Tags: mockito, byte-buddy

When I Try to run junit plugin tests in eclipse using Mockito 2 (version 2.0.54 beta), calling 
`org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Class<T>, MockSettings)` 
fails with stack trace above.

I manage to workaround the issue by doing this

```
ClassLoader loader = Tread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Mockito.class.getClassLoader());
try {
  org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Class<T>, MockSettings);
} finally {
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader)
}
```

That does not seems right, and requires lot of work to move from mockito 1 to mockito 2, is there any other way to be able to use mockito in osgi environment ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error invoking java.lang.ClassLoader#findClass
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Resolved.loadClass(ClassInjector.java:401)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.inject(ClassInjector.java:210)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:204)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:119)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4350)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockBytecodeGenerator.generateMockClass(MockBytecodeGenerator.java:60)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.CachingMockBytecodeGenerator$CachedBytecodeGenerator.generate(CachingMockBytecodeGenerator.java:72)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.CachingMockBytecodeGenerator$CachedBytecodeGenerator.getOrGenerateMockClass(CachingMockBytecodeGenerator.java:64)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.CachingMockBytecodeGenerator.get(CachingMockBytecodeGenerator.java:27)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createProxyClass(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:54)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:27)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:54)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1443)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1356)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/internal/creation/bytebuddy/MockMethodInterceptor$MockAccess
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Resolved.loadClass(ClassInjector.java:397)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$MockAccess
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:531)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader.loadClass(MultipleParentClassLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 66 more
```

Comment: This is a bug in Mockito. Please report this as an issue to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is resolved in a recent build of Mockito.